# IRC-Bot in Ruby: PRIVMSG sends only last word of string

Tags: ruby, irc

I'm on learning ruby and I took a already done IRC-Bot from the web which just connects to a given serven and not much more.
Then I added some features (in my case I try to implement a voting where to eat lunch).

Now these work fine so far but I don't know if the ruby script does something wrong or there is something wrong with the IRC-server.

On the one I tested the Bot it worked well, giving an output like this:

```
09:14 < Wayne> !EssNA
09:14 < EssNABot> [-=EssNA-Vote=-]
09:14 < EssNABot> Options are: 
09:14 < EssNABot> McDonalds. 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Currywurst 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Hendl..... 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Salatbar.. 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Griechr... 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Metzger... 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Merowinger 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Lidl...... 0
09:14 < EssNABot> Voting time is 600 seconds.
```

The bot itself sees that like this:

```
--> PRIVMSG #test [-=EssNA-Vote=-]
--> PRIVMSG #test Options are:
--> PRIVMSG #test McDonalds. 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Currywurst 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Hendl..... 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Salatbar.. 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Griechr... 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Metzger... 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Merowinger 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Lidl...... 0
--> PRIVMSG #test Voting time is 600 seconds.
```

But on the irc which it should run on if its done the output users will see looks like this:

```
09:14 < Wayne> !EssNA
09:14 < EssNABot> [-=EssNA-Vote=-]
09:14 < EssNABot> are:
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> 0
09:14 < EssNABot> seconds.
```

The output the bot gives is the same as on the server on which the output for users works.

Seems to me that the problem is the IRC-server, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Yours,
Marius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to add colon (':') after nickname, i.e. PRIVMSG #channel :Message

Comment: That seems to work :) Thank you! So there has to be a config thing that the other IRC-Server lets the PRIVMSG send completely although there is no colon after the channel...

Comment: Actually that's how IRC server process not well-formed message. According to IRC protocol RFC, message should contain that colon.

Comment: Oh good to know! Then I obviously tested on a non-RFC conform server, thanks for that, too :)

Answer (score 2):

[NIckolay O.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591714/irc-bot-in-ruby-privmsg-sends-only-last-word-of-string/4591743#4591743) is correct, but just to clarify what's going on here:

Each IRC protocol command consists of several fields, separated by whitespace.  The exception to this is when the first character of a field is a colon `:` - in this case, the remainder of the command following the colon is a single field (this allows the last field in the command to contain whitespace).

So, when your bot was sending incorrect messages like this:

```
PRIVMSG #test Voting time is 600 seconds.
```

...the message contained 7 fields (`PRIVMSG`, `#test`, `Voting`, `time`, `is`, `600` and `seconds.`).  However, a `PRIVMSG` command should only contain two fields following the `PRIVMSG` - the channel and the message to send.  In this case, the server was apparently picking the *last* field as the message (it would also have been unsurprising for it to pick the field following the channel instead).

The correct message, like this:

```
PRIVMSG #test :Voting time is 600 seconds.
```

...instead contains three fields (`PRIVMSG`, `#test`, and `Voting time is 600 seconds.`).  This is now a correctly formatted `PRIVMSG` command.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, didn't dig too deep into IRC protocol.